# SNMP Mibs and Agent

Tags: linux, nagios, snmp, agent, supervisord

I got an answer to you, I've got a supervisor server (Nagios+Centreon), how could I add a constructor specific mib into my Server?

Would I need any special Agent with these mibs?

Answer (score 2):

Not quite sure if I understand your question... But if you're looking for where to put $CUSTOMER MIBs, then that's in the `/usr/share/snmp/mibs` folder on most systems.

Comment: In fact, I would like to know, if I'm obligate to use the specific constructor Agent or the default Net-SNMPd agent is already able to read correctly the constructors mibs.